# MVC button not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, button, c#-4.0, submit

I have a  home controller with a view:

Index.html

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetModules", "Incom", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
    <input id="button" type="button" value="Get Modules" />
}
```

The incom controller has the function:

```
public ActionResult GetModules()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hey");
            return View("Index");
        }
```

The corresponding view is:

```
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
@{
// ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h1>we are here</h1>
```

When I try to run the application, the button does not take me to the new page. Could anyone help me understand what am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `type="button"` to `type="submit"` so it **submits** and your method should be marked `[HttpPost]`

Comment: Thank you Stephen.. It worked for me!!